# Repeater: show footer even when the DataSource is empty

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, repeater

Is it possible to always show the header and footer of an ASP.NET repeater, regardless if it contains no data or not?

I am quite aware that this question has been asked before by people wanting to display some kind of informative message, but in my situation, it's all about providing the client with the means to *populate* the very same `Repeater` with data using input fields in the footer. The situations might be similar, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an article that should help you with this,

basically the trick is here:

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Repeater1.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                Label lblFooter = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEmptyData");
                lblFooter.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

so you populate the Footer also when there are no items...

see full article here and good luck.

[Handling Empty Data in an ASP.NET Repeater control](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=271)